# Registry access restrictions in IE11 Enhanced Protected Mode

Tags: internet-explorer-11, windows-8.1, ieaddon

I have a plugin that is being loaded to the IE and tries to read the registry in

> HKCU\Software...

path, and being denied. What are the paths in registry (if any) that are permitted to the add-on that should be compatible with the EPM, for read/write? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is not well documented by Microsoft/MSDN but [this preso by Mark Yason](http://conference.hitb.org/hitbsecconf2013kul/materials/D2T1%20-%20Mark%20Vincent%20Yason%20-%20Diving%20Into%20IE10%27s%20Enhanced%20Protected%20Mode%20Sandbox.pdf) has some good info.

It describes that access is based upon the “ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES” [ACE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc246052.aspx), which gives read access to the following:

- HKCU\Software...\Explorer\RunMRU
- HKCU\Software...\Explorer\RecentDocs
- HKCU\Software...\Internet Explorer\TypedURLs
- HKLM\Software...\Low Rights\ElevationPolicy
- HKLM\Software...\Windows NT\CurrentVersion (Registered Owner/Org.)

And it lets you write to:

- HKCU\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppContainer\Storage\

Note that these are registry areas controlled by MSFT and their access can change in the future.

However, being controlled by an ACE means that access can be obtained via out-of-band means, such as an installer.